# Left rotation and right rotation in C

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to rotate the given string to left or right in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678707/how-to-rotate-the-given-string-to-left-or-right-in-c)

So i am write code that encrypt a string. As known as Ceasar cipher.

But instead of constantly doing right rotation.
for Shift = 1,   A=65, so i do 65+shift = 66, which is B.  ... C=>D.D=>E....
What if i want to do left rotation as well?

Now, A(65) => Z(90), B(66) =>A(65), C(67)=>B(65)...Y(89)=>X(88)

Is known that we can just do like original - shift, except for A(65).

so instead of creating a if(notA)... else(handle A).

Are there any elegant way to do so? In addition, if the shift is other number,there are more cases to consider...
Its there any other way to do so? like using mod or something??

Comment: Subtract 'A' from the value to make the range of letters start at 0, then use addition/subtraction and the modulo operator `%` to wrap the result into the range 0..25, then add 'A' again to get your final letter (:

Comment: The same "problem" occurs when doing normal shifts, you must map Z to A (`(letter + 26 + shift)%26`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look-up table.

```
    int shift;
    char inputstr[100]; //Dynamically allocate inputstr if needed.

   //Get values for 'shift' and 'inputstr'

    char encrypt[100]; //Resulting encrypted array
    char *alpha = "AB.....Z";

   // 
    for(i=0;i<strlen(inputStr);i++)
    encrypt[i] = alpha[(inputStr[i] - alpha[0]+shift)%26];
```

Similarly, you can have other lookup tables if you want a mix of small letters, numbers etc and change the logic accordingly.

Comment: That code only ever uses `alpha[0]` so there is no need of an array, it is the value 'A'. Is there a typo?

Comment: THanks for your time.
if you do ..%26 + alpha[0], the result is bigger than 65 isn't it??
I think simply alpha[(inputStr[i] - alpha[0]+shift)%26 will be correct?

Comment: Oh yes, that's right. corrected it now.

Comment: What happens when `inputStr[i] - alpha[0] + shift` is negative (assuming shift is allowed to be negative). I just wrote this and I got the index = -2%26 which is -2 in c.

Comment: Yes, i have the some question, if but if i google it, the answer is 24, which is desired.
Anyway to get around this??

Comment: @qwrqwr I wrote the function into a test program and printed it out and it was `-2` it didn't wrap. You could do `(inputStr[i] - alpha[0] + shift + 26) % 26` and I think it will work (at least it seems to in my tests)

Comment: I left the input validation to the OP. What if the user enters a char in unicode, shift etc. For the case if shift is negative then simply add 26 to shift before entering the loop.

Comment: Why do you need array? What about `'A'+(inputStr[i]-'A'+shift)%26`?

Answer (score 0):

Set the shift to always right and accept negative values to handle left shifts

so

```
char shift(int amount, char c) {
    return ((((c - 'A') + amount) + 26) % 26) + 'A';
}
```

if you call this with -3 it will shift to the left

Note this will only work for capital letters you can make it work for lower case only be changing 'A' to 'a' but it won't work for both capital and lowercase at the same time as written.

Edit I changed it into a single line

Here's the output

```
c = shift(-3, 'B'); = Y
c = shift(-3, 'F'); = C
c = shift(3, 'G'); = J
c = shift(3, 'Y'); = B
```