# Swapping blocks of elements in an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am working on C++.. am in a need to swap two blocks of elements in an array..

Say, {1,2,3,4,5,6} is my input array.. block {4,5} should be moved to beginning and the output array should be like {4,5,1,2,3,6}.. all i have is the start index and end index of the block {4,5}.. for doing this i am using a temp array, copying the blocks individually to temp array and moving it back to the original array, which is tedious

but i am sure there will be better methods to do this using memcpy or memmove.. any ideas?

Comment: Asked and answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616086/shifting-elements-in-an-array-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a standard algorithm designed specifically for this task called [`std::rotate()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/rotate/):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    int inputArray[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    ::printf("Before: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        ::printf("%d ", inputArray[i]);
    }
    ::printf("\n");

    int startIndex = 3; // refers to the number 4 in inputArray
    int endIndex = 5;   // refers one-past the number 5 in inputArray
    std::rotate(inputArray, inputArray+startIndex, inputArray+endIndex);

    ::printf("After: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        ::printf("%d ", inputArray[i]);
    }
    ::printf("\n");
}
```

Expected output:

> Before: 1 2 3 4 5 6
>
> After: 4 5 1 2 3 6

`std::rotate()` performs the rotation in-place via `std::swap()`, so there's no temporary array involved.

Comment: @Nawaz: Right, I got my indices messed up. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @In silico: That was exactly to the point.. Thanks a lot for that.. but i have one doubt which is a generic one(not sure how stupid it is).. as i see, we need to include <algorithm> library for using this "rotate" method.. generally, if we include such header files and compile, will the entire library's source code be copied to our executable (or) only the function definition of the one we have used will be copied to ur executable?

Comment: @inquisitive: `std::rotate` is a template function and its definition in its entirety can be found in a header file somewhere with your compiler, so there is no `.lib` or `.dll` file for it. In any case, the compiler should be smart enough to not compile in code the executable doesn't need.

Comment: fine.. i am using gcc compiler.. i ll see the difference in code size after inclusion..

Comment: @inquisitive: Did you compile with optimizations turned on?

Answer (score 2):

Bentley's "Programming Pearls" describes three algorithms for solving this problem. You can find slides for this specific problem here

http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/s02b.pdf

For example, the simplest algorithms would be the Reversal one. Just reverse the blocks that you need to swap, and then reverse the entire array. Done.

P.S. In your example "the entire array" would stand for the `1,2,3,4,5` subsequence (`6` is not included), since these are the blocks that you need to swap.

Reverse the blocks:

```
3, 2, 1, 5, 4
```

Reverse the whole thing

```
4, 5, 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: And there's a standard algorithm designed for this task called `std::reverse()`.